# Timeouts with core.async on ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I have a go-loop reading vals from a port in ClojureScript. After a pre-defined timeout (say, 5 seconds) I need to *exit the loop* and if no vals appeared for more than another predefined timeout (say, 200 milliseconds) I also need to *exit the loop*.

By exciting the loop I mean, end it and run something else, another function for example.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`alts!`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/alts!)

```
;; within your go-loop:

(let [[val ch] (alts! [my-ch (timeout 500)])]
  (when (identical? my-ch ch)
    ;; dispatch val here...
    (recur))
  ;; not calling recur here, to exit the loop
  )
```